# React Native: is it possible to make a component and all its children disappear?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

In my React Native app I have a `<View>` with several other elements nested inside it. Normally if I want to make a component disappear, I make its height go to 0, make its opacity 0, etc. But I want a universal way to apply a style to the `<View>` and have it and all its child components disappear.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition inside curly braces in jsx to show or hide component

```
<View>
  {
    condition && (
      <View> // <- View and its children will show only if condition is true
        //Children components
      </View>
    )
  }
</View>
```

Comment: I posted a similar question here if you have any insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391813/react-native-can-you-conditionally-render-jsx-based-on-the-existence-of-a-strin